# How does the pip function in Python work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, pip

I have been trying to install dependencies for a library on a colleagues Virtual Machine which is running XUbuntu 16.04. I have been able to install these dependencies on my own machine without a problem, however when attempting to install these dependencies using PIP on hers we get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package name> == <package version>
```

and

```
No matching distribution found for <package name> == <package version>
```

where package name and package version are the corresponding details for the specific package that pip gets stuck on (in one example this could be catfish==1.4.2). I was able to install this package on my computer, although I can't find the package using pip3 when I search. I am using Python 3.5.2 but Python 2.7 is also installed on my virtual machine.

I have tried a few things to figure out why this is the case but have not been able to reach a result. I strongly suspect that if I understood how exactly pip works I would be able to solve this problem. If anyone has any tips on what I could do or where to look to get to the bottom of this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a pip requirements.txt file?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: We actually ended reinstalling XUbuntu and trying again and it worked the second time around. I suspect this may have had something to do with the location of the Python installationon the computer and what the computer was choosing as the default Python executable (we have both 2.7 and 3.5.2) to run which was in the /usr/bin directory. The second time around we put it in the /usr/src/ directory.